$M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a rotation of set $\{ x^2 + z^2 = 4x-3, 1<x<2, -1<z<1 \}$ by $\pi$ around axis OZ. Find $\int_M\max(x,y,z) d \lambda_2$
$M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a surface created by rotation of set
$\{ x^2 + z^2 = 4x-3, \ 1<x<2, \  -1<z<1 \}$ by $\pi$ around axis OZ.
Find $\int_M \max(x,y,z) d \lambda_2$.

I know that $x^2 + z^2 = 4x-3 \iff x^2 - 4x + 4 + z^2 = 1 \iff (x-2)^2 + z^2 = 1$
So, we have a circle with radius equal to $1$ and with center in $(x = 2, z = 0)$. The values of x and z make it possible for the whole circle to appear. When we rotate it around OZ axis, we will obtain a part torus (not the full torus since we rotate only by $\pi)$. The values of x and y change as we rotate and the values of z stay constant.
As I see that, we have such situation:

But what to do next? How to calculate such an integral?

Do you mean $1 \leq x \leq 3$ instead of $1 < x < 2$ (and also $-1 \leq z \leq 1$ instead of $-1 < z < 1$)? Otherwise, your circle is half missing plus it has a gap at $(1, 0, 0)$.

I lost the part that it is rotated only by $\pi$, I'm sorry.

Maybe this is not the best way to do it since I got stuck in the last integral, but you can parameterize the torus (see Parametrisation of the surface a torus) by
$$
r(\theta,\phi) = ((\cos{\theta}+2)\cos{\phi},(\cos{\theta}+2)\sin{\phi},\sin{\theta})
$$
so using the relation
$$
\max{(x,y,z)} = \frac{x+y+2z+|x-y|+|x+y-2z+|x-y||}{4}
$$
the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{M} \max{(x,y,z)} \ d\lambda_2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \max{((\cos{\theta}+2)\cos{\phi},(\cos{\theta}+2)\sin{\phi},\sin{\theta})}\left\lVert \frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi} \right\rVert \ d\phi \ d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \left[\frac{(\cos{\theta}+2)\cos{\phi}+(\cos{\theta}+2)\sin{\phi}+2\sin{\theta}+|(\cos{\theta}+2)(\cos{\phi}-\sin{\phi})|}{4} +\frac{|(\cos{\theta}+2)\cos{\phi}+(\cos{\theta}+2)\sin{\phi}-2\sin{\theta}+|(\cos{\theta}+2)\cos{\phi}-(\cos{\theta}+2)\sin{\phi}||}{4}\right](2+\cos{\theta})\ d\phi \ d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\cos{\theta}+2)^2(\sin{\phi}+\cos{\phi}+|\cos{\phi}-\sin{\phi}|)}{4} +\frac{(2+\cos{\theta})\sin{\theta}}{2} + (2+\cos{\theta})\frac{|(\cos{\theta}+2)(\cos{\phi}+\sin{\phi})-2\sin{\theta}+(\cos{\theta}+2)|\cos{\phi}-\sin{\phi}||}{4} \ d\phi \ d\theta \\
&= \frac{18(1+\sqrt{2})\pi}{4} + 0 + \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} (2+\cos{\theta})\frac{|(\cos{\theta}+2)(\cos{\phi}+\sin{\phi})-2\sin{\theta}+(\cos{\theta}+2)|\cos{\phi}-\sin{\phi}||}{4} \ d\phi \ d\theta
\end{align*}
using symmetry the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
I = &\frac{9(1+\sqrt{2})\pi}{2} + 4\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (2+\cos{\theta})\frac{|(\cos{\theta}+2)(\cos{\phi}+\sin{\phi})-2\sin{\theta}+(\cos{\theta}+2)(\cos{\phi}-\sin{\phi})|}{4} \ d\phi \ d\theta \\
&= \frac{9(1+\sqrt{2})\pi}{2} + \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (2+\cos{\theta})|2(2+\cos{\theta})\cos{\phi}-2\sin{\theta}| \ d\phi \ d\theta \\
&= \frac{9(1+\sqrt{2})\pi}{2} +\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 2(2+\cos{\theta})^2 \cos{\phi} -4\sin{\theta} -2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta} \ d\phi \ d\theta \\
&= \frac{9(1+\sqrt{2})\pi}{2} +\int_{0}^{2\pi}2(2+\cos{\theta})^2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} -\pi\sin{\theta} -\frac{\pi \sin{2\theta}}{4} \ d\theta \\
&= \frac{9(1+\sqrt{2})\pi}{2} +9\sqrt{2}\pi = \frac{9(1+3\sqrt{2})\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}

The argument of the absolute value is always positive, and so, the integral is solvable. Note that for $\phi\in(0,\pi/4)$ we have $\cos\phi >\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}>0.7$ and $\frac{\sin \theta}{2+\cos\theta}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}<0.6$.

@MostafaAyaz you are right, I don't know why I didn't see this
